# How to set up MyControllerFactory for ASP.NET Core 3.x project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have implemented `IControllerFactory` and would like to set it up. I read that it was possible to do it with the following command

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

But I can't find `ControllerBuilder` under `Microsoft.AspNetCore` namespace. BTW, [`DefaultControllerFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.defaultcontrollerfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is not present in ASP.NET Core 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your own implementation in ConfigureServices, after calling AddMvc:

```
services.AddSingleton<IControllerFactory, MyCustomControllerFactory>();
```

This way it will get called whenever a controller is to be built.

Comment: then what is the default implementation type of name of the `IControllerFactory`, i still need fallback the request.